# How do I copy the QWebPage?

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, qwebview, qobject

I want to create my own custom page. This class inherit from [`QWebPage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html). But I want to create it copying values from an [`existing instance`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#page) so that I'll just add my own methods, override some stuff and then replace current page with my custom one with [`setPage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#setPage).

The issue is: `QObject` copy constructor doesn't seems to work:

```
class webpage : public QWebPage
{
public:
    //webpage(QObject* parent = 0);
    webpage(QWebPage*);
    void foo();
}

webpage::webpage(QWebPage *page)
    : QWebPage(*page)
{
}
```

result in the error:

> error: C2248: 'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'QObject'

My question is: How can I work around this? what I really want is copy the `page` parameter object to current object.

Comment: What kind of data you need to copy from one instance of QWebPage to another?

Comment: `QObject` has special design, that disables direct copy. You need to implement method `webpage * webpage::clone()` that will provide a deep copy with necessary logic.

Comment: You should mention, that it is for some reason disabled by design. See my answer below.

Comment: @vahancho: I'd like to make a shallow copy of the object to object being created in the `webpage::webpage(QWebPage *page)` constructor

Comment: @SaZ: I don't understand well, the object I want to copy is return value of `setPage()` of `QWebPage` type. How will I created a `clone()` method inside `QWebPage` class?

Comment: @Jack you misunderstood that `QWebPage` and in content is different things. `QWebPage` is not designed to be a base class, so you should not inherit it. You need to redesign your application, it is not clear, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code:

```
class webpage : public QWebPage
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    //webpage(QObject* parent = 0);
    webpage::webpage(QWebPage *page)
    : QWebPage(page)
    {
    }

    void foo();
};
```

The constructor of QWebPage expects a pointer, but you dereferenced it. That caused your described error.

QWebPage is derived from QObject, which means it neither has a copy constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by Design:

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
>   Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that you should use pointers to QObject (or to
>   your QObject subclass) where you might otherwise be tempted to use
>   your QObject subclass as a value. For example, without a copy
>   constructor, you can't use a subclass of QObject as the value to be
>   stored in one of the container classes. You must store pointers.

[http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator]

I'm afraid you have to create your own set method to copy the content and / or properties you need if you still want to create a kind of copy.

Another option would be to create a class which contains a QWebPage pointer as a member. You can write your own methods using the inner QWebPage and thus create custom methods how to use the existing QWebPage instance. But this will only work if you don't need to use the existing instance in another context.

Comment: Jack is asking about copy, not about Qt memory model or inheritance.

Comment: That's right and I say one should not copy QObjects. And there is my explanation why.